# iOS5 digital signal processing library?

Tags: integration, signal-processing, ios5, fft

I have a discrete time signal which is a sum of sine waves. It is not an audio signal. Is there some library/framework for iOS or C/c++ that would help me accomplish tasks like discrete time integration or FFT?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - look at [Apple's Accelerate framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Accelerate/Reference/AccelerateFWRef/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009465) - it has various DSP functions including FFTs etc